# How to read a file for special lines in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I just want to read even line number from a file in bash shell, how to do it?

Also I just want to read the fifth line of a file, then how do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1' <filename>
```

For the second one:

```
awk 'NR == 5' <filename>
```

You can also use sed to get numbers in a specified range:

```
sed -ne '5,5p' <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tail` command. Put it in a for loop for the first case and the second is totally trivial if you get the first.

Or maybe you could even use awk:

```
awk NR==5 file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

To read even number files using gnu-sed:

```
sed -n "2~2 p" file
```

To print specific line # from a file using sed:

```
sed '5q;d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

for example lines between 3 and 6

```
awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=6'`
```

These is a help to improve it(but not completed)

```
#!/bin/bash                           
test=`cat input.txt | awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=6'`
while read line; do
    #do stuff
done <input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk is often the answer (or, nowadays, Perl, Python etc. too)

If for some reason you must do it with only bash and the basic shell utilities:

```
cat file | \
while read line; do 
   i=$(( (i + 1) % 2 )) 
   if [[ $i -eq 0 ]]; then 
      echo $line // or whatever else you wanted to do with it
   fi
done
```

And to get a specific line:

```
cat file | head -5 | tail -1
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`; use `while read line; do ...; done < file` and `head -5 file`